# Are newly inserted records available to subsequent SQL commands within the same transaction?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, sqltransaction

Let's say I have some C# code that executes two SQL commands:

```
var MyTransaction = DbConnection.BeginTransaction();
//using MyTransaction: INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (ID, SOURCE_FIELD) VALUES (99, 'HELLO')
//using MyTransaction: UPDATE TABLE_2 SET DESTINATION_FIELD = (SELECT SOURCE_FIELD FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID = 99)
MyTransaction.Commit();
```

Will the second SQL statement see the new record with ID '99' even though I didn't commit the transaction until the end?

Comment: Yes it will be available.

Comment: Yes it will, but only for that session (exception: when using `read uncommitted/nolock`, or when binding to another session with `sp_bindsession` the you can see someone else's uncommitted rows)

Comment: Yes, because it is in the same transaction.  If you ran the query separately in another session, the records would not be visible.